# Is there such thing as an exponential/logarithmic inverse?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, inverse, tetration

Okay, let me explain.

First, there's the additive inverse, or the negative form of a number.
*i.e. the additive inverse of $2$ is $-2$.*

Then, there's the multiplicative inverse, or the reciprocal of a number.
*i.e. the multiplicative inverse of $2$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.*

The question I have is if there's a logarithmic inverse. Is there, or is there not?

I believe it could be $2\uparrow \uparrow-1$ ($2$ tetrated to $-1$), but I can'r be sure, and Google isn't giving me any answers.

Comment: To talk about an inverse, you must first talk about an identity.  For addition, that would be $0$ since you have $0+x = x+0 = x$ for all $x$.  For multiplication that would be $1$ since $1\times x = x\times 1 = x$ for all $x$.  Exponentiation does not have an identity.  There does not exist some value $a$ such that $a^x = x^a = x$ for all $x$.

Comment: @JMoravitz on the other hand exponentiation does have a right-identity, namely $1$, as $x^1 = x$ for all $x$.  One could reasonably seek a right-inverse, i.e. an element $\hat{x}$ such that $x^{\hat{x}} = 1$, but this is unfortunately trivial, as $\hat{x} = 0$ for all $x$. So there's just nothing to see here.

Comment: Given a value $x$, an "inverse" for an operation $\star$ would have been a value $y$ such that $x\star y = y\star x = e$ for whatever the identity $e$ is for that operation.  For addition, that would be $x + (-x) = (-x) + x = 0$.  For multiplication (*for nonzero $x$*) that would be $x\times (x^{-1}) = (x^{-1})\times x = 1$.  Without an appropriate identity for exponentiation, there does not exist the concept of inverses.

Comment: Why do you think that the inverse tetration (if this could be reasonably defined) would be an inverse of the exponentiation ? Tetration is repeated exponentiation , it has a higher level than exponentiation.

Comment: @Peter I think it could be a reasonable guess, given that the additive inverse can be written in terms of multiplication ($-x = x\times(-1)$) and the multiplicative inverse can be written in terms of exponentiation ($\frac{1}{x}=x^{-1}$)